# Extract folder from zip file

Tags: c++, c, zip, extract

I have one question, I need extract folder from zip. I use c/c++. I searched it in google but didn't find. I found extract one(or more) file(s) from zip, but I have folder in zip file and I need extract it. How does it?

Help me pls, I read about minizip and found how extract files, but I didn't understand how extract folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try MiniZip
http://www.winimage.com/zLibDll/minizip.html

Then using the unzGoToFirstFile and unzGoToNextFile you move in the files inside the zip, use the unzGetCurrentFileInfo to obtain the path of the files, if it's the folder you want, unzip it.

Comment: thx, I used minizip, but I couldn't extract folder. After wrestling with minizip for 2 hours, I did it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [zlib](http://www.zlib.net/) and [7zip](http://7-zip.org/sdk.html) ? they both provide SDKs.